# Managed Application scoped bean creates multiple times

Tags: java, jsf, javabeans

I have beans

```
@ManagedBean(name="HistoryBean")
@ApplicationScoped
public class HistoryBean
{...}

@ManagedBean(name="ViewBean")
@ApplicationScoped
public class ViewBean
{
        public void setHistoryBean(HistoryBean historyBean) 
        {this.historyBean = historyBean;}

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{HistoryBean}")
    private HistoryBean historyBean;
}
```

I want to HistoryBean was created only once, but it creates on each request(?) with clean state. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Can you show your imports for `ApplicationScoped` and `ManagedBean` ?

Comment: import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

Comment: If you have found the answer to this question, please add it as an answer (and only an answer) to this question. There is no need to edit your question to include the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trouble was in wrong annotation imports. You need to use annotation which are from javax.faces.bean package.